# Twilio statuscallback POST causing 15003 error

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I am building an app using ASP.Net core 3.1. Twilio voice call was successful. Now I have trouble capturing statuscallback. My logs & twilo logs show that twilio posted the statuscallback to https://myapp.com/call/events *with error 15003 meaning HTTP 400*.

This my code

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Events([FromForm] StatusRequest statusRequest)
{
_logger.LogWarning($"Twilio status call back...");
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?  It's not hitting the log in the action method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was  'Antiforgery token validation failed.' exception causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the error message description:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/15003.

Possible Solutions

**Ensure your application responds to callbacks with:**

- 200 OK
- Content-Type: text/xml
- Valid TwiML